# Mongoose- Run a function to all Entries in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a beginner in NodeJs and MongoDB. I have a user schema where I have a field which is an array that is filled by the user's input value. After users enter the value, the admin also passes an array of correct answers. I want to create a function which runs on all users array field and on correct answer store the score in users schema. Just wanted to know how do I run the function on all entries of the collection.

```
//Final result schema by the admin
const resultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    matchday:Number,
    homeTeam:String,
    awayTeam:String,
    utcDate:Date,
    finalUpdateTime:Date,
    result:Array
})


//The predicted answer Schema
const predictSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'User',
        required:[true, 'Predicted Team must belong to a User']
    },
    teamData:Array,
    matchday: Number,
    score:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    createdAt: {
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    },
    lastUpdated:Date,
},{
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true,
      },
      toObject: {
        virtuals: true,
      },
})
```

Comment: Can you add more details, post your schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a static method for your schema. Statics are methods that can be invoked directly by a Model.

[See here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics)

You can pass array of correct answers to this method and check the answers for each user in your collection. You can retrieve all users using [Find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Comment: I have 2 schemas, One is the predicted answers schema and one is the answer schema by the admin, where would I insert the static method because i have to update the score of in the predicted answer schema. I have now edited the question with the schemas

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue and it works but not sure if its the correct way to do it

```
exports.updateUserScore = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await Predict.find({ matchday: req.body.matchday });
  user.map(async (el) => {
    let score = 0;

    el.teamData.map((e) => {
      if (req.body.teamData.includes(e)) score = score + 1;
    });
    console.log(score, el._id);
    await Predict.findByIdAndUpdate(el._id, { score: score });
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'Updated User Score Successfully',
  });
};
```